# Information Logging stops appearing part way through azure worker role onStart()

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging, visual-studio-2015

I have a worker role that talks to an azure service bus in its onStart() method and therefore takes some time to complete.

I have both Error and Informational TraceLogging in this method (the error logging is just there to prove that the code was executing normally and not blocking).

```
Trace.TraceInformation($"Info: About to check queue exists"); 
Trace.TraceError($"Error: About to check queue exists"); 
if (!(namespaceManager.QueueExists(sourceQueueName)))
{
    Trace.TraceError($"Message = Unable to find source queue: {SourceQueueName} in service bus: {ConnectionString}");
}
else
{
    Trace.TraceInformation($"Info: Creating queue client for: {sourceQueueName}");
    Trace.TraceError($"Error: Creating queue client for: {sourceQueueName}");
    sourceClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, sourceQueueName);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
EventName="MessageEvent" Message="Info: About to check queue exists" TraceSource="WaWorkerHost.exe"
EventName="MessageEvent" Message="Error: About to check queue exists" TraceSource="WaWorkerHost.exe"
EventName="MessageEvent" Message="Error: Creating queue client for: myqueue" TraceSource="WaWorkerHost.exe"
```

Actually there is more logging above the call to namepace manager, so I can see that the information logging stops in a slightly random place, but always before the call to namespaceManager.QueueExists which is a blocking network call.

When I deploy my role I always set application logs to informational through visual studio after it has deployed (update diagnostics on the cloud service in server explorer). After every deployment the logging level is somehow always automatically reset to error so I have to do this.

So I assume that during a 'publish' the information logging is still switched on from last time, but at some point during the redeploy it switches back to error (until I go back in and set it back to information logging).

Is there a way to get information logging during publish? I had assumed that the logging levels set in the diagnostics configuration were about what logs got copied to azure storage rather than what was logged in the first place. Is that not the case? How can I see information logging throughout the onStart() process - and between publish and manually updating diagnostics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update the diagnostics.wadcfgx file for my worker role.

I changed the `scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter` in `DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration` from Error to Information:

```
<DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
        <WadCfg>
            <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
                ...
                <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Information" />
            </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
            ...
         </WadCfg>
     </PublicConfig>
     ...
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get information logging during publish? I had assumed that the logging levels set in the diagnostics configuration were about what logs got copied to azure storage rather than what was logged in the first place. Is that not the case? How can I see information logging throughout the onStart() process - and between publish and manually updating diagnostics?

I have also created a test cloud service in my side and published to the azure. It works well. If you set the right diagnostics configuration(azure) before published. Azure will not change the setting.

Notice: Make sure you have selected the right service configuration.

[image]

After published to azure, you could find the diagnostics is right.

[image]

If you want to see the published log, you could use azure web portal to open the Operation log (classic).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brando. I tried this but I still get application logs at level error on subsequent publish. And I have to check the transfer ETW logs also in diagnostics settings (diagnostics extension).

Comment: Could you please tell me which Visual studio version and diagnostics version you have used now? In my opinion, the azure will not change the diagnostics setting when you published the application. I used the newest VS2017 and newest diagnostics. I suggest you could try to update the VS and try again.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. OK I will try VS2017 on a different PC. Thank you.